# Template function overload for type containing a type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-templates

I'm trying to do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <list>

template <typename T>
void f(T t) {
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename V>
void f(T<std::tuple<V>> t) {
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    f(std::list<double>{}); // should use first template
    f(std::vector<std::tuple<int>>{}); // should use second template
}
```

What is the simplest way to do this in C++14? I thought that I could sort of pattern match in this way but the compiler won't have it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The template parameter `T` is used as a template-name, so it should be declared as [template template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter). e.g.

```
template <template <typename...> class T, typename V>
//        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
void f(T<std::tuple<V>> t) {
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/JXC67262)

Comment: I checked your answer and it does compile successfully, however at least in MSVS 2017 CE, the 2nd problem or function call from the OP' main function is not using the 2nd version of the function template it is in fact using the 1st. I don't know if this has to do with compiler optimizations or not, but I think it is something to be aware of. Other than that; good answer!

Comment: @FrancisCugler I tried it with Clang and GCC, both work as expected; [VS](http://rextester.com/SUHT22605) seems failing to deduce the type `T` for the 2nd function template, I'm not sure, it might be bug.

Comment: Oh okay because I did end up asking that as a question found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511401/function-temple-overload-resolution