# Function Template Overload Resolution & Compiler Optimizations

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-optimization, overload-resolution

I was looking at this question found here [Template function overload for type containing a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511121/template-function-overload-for-type-containing-a-type#44511121)

Where the OP [user2079802](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2079802/user2079802) provided this code for his/her question:

> I'm trying to do the following:
>
> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <vector>
> #include <tuple>
>
> template <typename T>
> void f(T t) {
>     std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
> }
>
> template <typename T, typename V>
> void f(T<std::tuple<V>> t) {
>     std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
> }
>
> int main() {
>     f(std::list<double>{}); // should use first template
>     f(std::vector<std::tuple<int>>{}); // should use second template
> }
> ```
>
> What is the simplest way to do this in C++14? I thought that I could sort of pattern match in this way but the compiler won't have it.

And [songyuanyao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3309790/songyuanyao) provided this answer:

> The template parameter `T` is used as a template-name, so it should be declared as [template template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter). e.g.
>
> ```
> template <template <typename...> class T, typename V>
> //        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> void f(T<std::tuple<V>> t) {
>     std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
> }
> ```
>
> [LIVE](http://rextester.com/JXC67262)

---

The answer that was provided did in fact fix the compilation errors and the code does run correctly. I'm asking a question about this code snippet for clarity. The OP was originally trying to pattern match the template types but had improper syntax for template template parameters. When I ran the answer through my IDE, Compiler & Debugger {MSVS 2017 CE} running on a 64bit Intel Windows 7 machine I happen to notice that in the OP's function calls in their main function:

> ```
> f(std::list<double>{});
> f(std::vector<std::tuple<int>>{});
> ```

That the 2nd function call is in fact calling the 1st function template and not the 2nd. This does raise a couple of questions:

- Is this happening due to compiler optimizations?
- Is this a result of overload resolution?
- What is actually happening under the hood of the compiler when it
    is choosing to use the first function template over the 2nd?
- Or is this a bug with MSVC compiler?

Comment: Eh, do you get the output "1 2"? Or do you draw this conclusion "the 2nd function call is in fact calling the 1st function template" from what you see in the debugger?

Comment: @DanielJour I'm getting a printed value of `1` instead of `2` so it is calling the 1st function and not the 2nd.

Comment: It is a bug in the MSVC compiler.

Comment: @n.m. Check my answer to see that it is not in fact a bug in MSVC (yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not actually a bug in the MSVC compiler. It's really a result of an ambiguity in the standard concerning default template parameters.

You see, `std::vector` actually has 2 template arguments: the type, and an allocator.

If you refactor the answer from that question to account for the allocator

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t) {
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
}

template <template <typename...> class T, typename V>
void f(T<std::tuple<V>, std::allocator<std::tuple<V>>> t) {
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}
```

It will work properly in all compilers: [msvc demo](http://rextester.com/WSQ21257), [gcc demo](http://rextester.com/JLENHV74448), [clang demo](http://rextester.com/JNGR64280).

[Here's the original defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#150) (CWG 150)

[P0522R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html) has the latest discussion as of November 2016, where they propose that the kind of partial template matching you reference in songyuanyao's answer will be correct according to the standard.

The changes proposed in P0522R0 are being incorporated into the C++17 standard (draft N4296 was the one I checked). Until the standard is finalized and MSVC claims to have full C++17 support, I wouldn't call it a bug in the compiler. For now, they acknowledge that this specific proposal has not yet been incorporated into their compiler as of VS 2017.3 [P2] ([source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/))

Comment: It's looks like a slightly different issue. The example in the report is rejected by the three major compilers while OP's code works as expected with g++ and clang++. Your proposed solution misses the point. The dea of using a parameter pack is that we don't want to know or care what other template parameters might be there. Your solution forces the programmer to know that `T` accepts two arguments, the second one being `std::allocator<...>` (we could write `template<class,class>class T` instead which works even in C++03). Fortunately it is easy to [fix](https://pastebin.com/FmKfgqQY).

Comment: @n.m. The explicit use of `std::allocator` was for demonstration purposes :-). As for it being a different issue than the report, I am inclined to (respectfully) disagree. OPs code does not work as expected in gcc with the C++14 option [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RTRvJJAicYDUkuND), whereas it does work properly with the C++17 option [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/x0w1SsMvr0s1pDA1)

Comment: so the behaviour has changed between gcc 6 and 7 (I have only checked gcc 6).

Comment: Thank you for the answer; it does give some good insight and the resources of the documents is a great help. I'll leave the question open for now to see if other answers are provided before I decide to accept  your answer or not.

Comment: When I checked out the live code for all three compilers; all three prints out `2` with the added `param` for the `std::allocator<>`, and when I remove that `2nd` `param` from the function definition and run the three different compilers both `gcc` and `clang` still print out `2` where `msvc` prints out `1`.  So it has come to my understanding that it is the manner in which each compiler tries to parse the source code and the documentations does show a proposal about the requirements for a `template template parameter` for the new standard.

Comment: @AndyG It's been a few days since you have provided this answer and I've been checking it regularly but I'll still continue to leave it open for a little while longer and if after say a couple of weeks if no one else can provide a reasonable answer for me to compare to then I'll be more than willing to accept your answer.